# Modifying text column wise with sed/awk

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, text-processing

I have an input data with three columns (tab separated) like this:

```
  a  mrna_185598_SGL 463
  b  mrna_9210_DLT   463
  c  mrna_9210_IND   463
  d  mrna_9210_INS   463
  e  mrna_9210_SGL   463
```

How can I use sed/awk to modify it into
four columns data that looks like this:

```
a  mrna_185598 SGL   463
b  mrna_9210   DLT   463
c  mrna_9210   IND   463
d  mrna_9210   INS   463
e  mrna_9210   SGL   463
```

In principle I want to split the original "mrna" string into 2 parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($2,a,"_"); $2=a[1]"_"a[2]"\t"a[3] }1'  file
```

output

```
# ./shell.sh
a       mrna_185598     SGL     463
b       mrna_9210       DLT     463
c       mrna_9210       IND     463
d       mrna_9210       INS     463
e       mrna_9210       SGL     463
```

use nawk on Solaris

and if you have bash

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r a b c
do
    front=${b%_*}
    back=${b##*_}
    printf "$a\t$front\t$back\t$c\n"
done <"file"
```

Answer (score 2):

gawk:

```
{
  print $1 "\t" gensub(/_/, "\t", 2, $2) "\t" $3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided they don't look too much different from what you've posted:

```
sed -E 's/mrna_([0-9]+)_/mrna_\1\t/'
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to use sed. instead use tr

```
cat *FILENAME* | tr '_[:upper:]{3}\t' '\t[:lower:]{3}\t' >> *FILEOUT*
```

cat *FILENAME* will print out the files witch will then be piped ('|') to tr (translate).
tr will replace anything that has an underscore followed by 3 uppercase characters and then a tab with a tab instead of the underscore.  Then it will append it to *FILEOUT*.

Comment: useless use of cat. pass the file to tr instead. --. tr 'blah 'blah' < file >> fileout. and did you test your command properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat test.txt
  a  mrna_185598_SGL 463
  b  mrna_9210_DLT   463
  c  mrna_9210_IND   463
  d  mrna_9210_INS   463
  e  mrna_9210_SGL   463

$ cat test.txt | sed -E 's/(\S+)_(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/\1\t\2\t\3/'
  a  mrna_185598    SGL 463
  b  mrna_9210  DLT 463
  c  mrna_9210  IND 463
  d  mrna_9210  INS 463
  e  mrna_9210  SGL 463
```

Comment: useless use of cat. pass the file name to sed instead. -- `sed 'options' filename`

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '{$1=$1; $0=gensub(/_/,"\t",2);print}' file

a mrna_185598   SGL 463
b mrna_9210 DLT 463
c mrna_9210 IND 463
d mrna_9210 INS 463
e mrna_9210 SGL 463
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/_/\t/2' file
```

Replace the second occurrence of a `_` by a tab.